# Redirect after empty login username and password

Tags: login

I have chosen to display a login form in the first page of my wordpress website. If the user logs in successfully, he gets redirected to a specific webpage. If he enters a wrong password, he gets redirected to the login page again. The problem happens when someone does not enter username and password: he gets redirected to the wordpress admin login page.

How can I redirect empty username logins back to the main login page ?

this is the code I am using to redirect failed attempts :

```
add_filter('login_redirect', '_catch_login_error', 10, 3);

function _catch_login_error($redir1, $redir2, $wperr_user)
{
    if(!is_wp_error($wperr_user) || !$wperr_user->get_error_code()) return $redir1;

    switch($wperr_user->get_error_code())
    {
        case 'incorrect_password':
        case 'empty_password':
        case 'invalid_username':
        default:
            wp_redirect(home_url()); // modify this as you wish
    }

    return $redir1;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check for an empty user login in the `$_REQUEST` array:

```
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['user_login'] ) // && or || empty( $_REQUEST['user_pass'] )
  return $redirect_to_whereever_you_want;
```

But this filter is to late. It is called **after** the user is logged in. You have to use the `'wp_authenticate'` action, this is one of the earliest action in the login process:

```
add_action( 'wp_authenticate', '_catch_empty_user', 1, 2 );

function _catch_empty_user( $username, $pwd ) {
  if ( empty( $username ) ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to_whereever_you_want );
    exit();
  }
}
```